# Exporting WebGL For Mobile Browsers

Tags: unity, webgl, unity-webgl

I was asked by a client to create a pretty simple 3D game that will be embedded on a website, a plain landing page that will contain the game and will be played on mobile devices.

The game itself has no complexity whatsoever, not in the functional aspect and not in the lighting/shaders aspect - the basic functionality is a simple finger swipe in order to "throw" a ball.

I have checked and concluded that opening a webGL game on mobile devices might cause issues and only high-end devices can run the game smoothly.

My question is -
Is there a go-to solution or any solution in which I can develop the game on Unity and build it for webGL in a way that it will be compatible with mobile devices?
Or my only option is to develop the game using plain JS?

Comment: Have you looked at [Project Tiny](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.tiny@0.23/manual/index.html)?

Comment: Hi, that looks like a good option, although it might be a bit inconvenient to code with DOTS as its workflow is slightly different. I also looked at LunaLabs, their core product is exporting playables directly from Unity. I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use Luna for embedding the game in a web page instead of using it as a playable, as they embedded the games here down the page - https://lunalabs.io/luna-playable/

Comment: Hi can you tell us what solution did you use in the end tnx.